# Delegate section doesn't run on client-side of MMO

Tags: c#, delegates

This code here is mostly fine, but it doesn't appear to be running the delegate section. I marked where it isn't working with comments:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using ogclient_framework;

[PacketOpcode(1)]
public class Packet_01_Login : Packet  {


    public override void Decode()

    {
        bool success = ByteBuffer.ReadBoolean ();
        if (success) 
        {
            int networkId = ByteBuffer.ReadInt();
            Debug.Log ("Successful login, network ID:" + networkId);

        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log ("Not correct/server down");

            int opcode = ByteBuffer.ReadInt();

            Debug.Log ("test");
            //BELOW THIS SECTION DOES NOT RUN, BUT NO ERRORS SHOWN, THE DEBUG LOG 'TEST1' IS NOT PRINTED BUT THE DEBUG LOG ABOVE IS.
            GameClient.Singleton.Prepare(delegate{
                InterfaceManager.Singleton.loginMessage(opcode);
                Debug.Log ("test1");

            });

        }
    }
}
```

Why would it not work? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Hiya Will! Quick question; could you please edit your question and tag it with its language?

Comment: Sorry I am new here, what do you mean? I tried to tag English and it didnt allow it. But please, this problem it rather urgent and I have had to progress. I am using the OGserver api as well.

Comment: Ah, which programming language is it? Like, C++, Objective-C, etc.?

Comment: Its in C# and I am using the OGserver API.

Comment: how about adding try/catch block around GameClient.Singleton.Prepare method?

Answer (score 1):

> This code here is mostly fine, but it doesn't appear to be running the
>   delegate section.

That's because this code *doesn't* execute the delegate.

This code *passes* the delegate to `GameClient.Singleton.Prepare`, but it's up to `GameClient.Singleton.Prepare` whether and when *it* executes the delegate.

Consider the following code:

```
    private delegate void MyDelegate();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prepare(delegate
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("test1");
        });
    }

    private void prepare(MyDelegate d)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Prepare");

        //Maybe invoke the delegate, maybe not yet
        //     d.Invoke();
    }
```

When button1_Click fires, you will only see "Prepare" in the debug trace--not "test1", unless you uncomment the `Invoke` statement.

Comment: So how would I add this to my current c# script to so it does as I want, which is, for the code ' InterfaceManager.Singleton.loginMessage(opcode);' to run. Getting this to work is of up-most importance as a similar block of code will be used if the user has a successful login. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on the ogclient stuff you're using. Don't they have sample code?